# Flutter ble writing fails

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, bluetooth-lowenergy

Flutter ble -  write characteristic error

I'm not being able to write on ble pheriperal device, using `flutter_blue` library, it throws this exception:

```
Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(write_characteristic_error, service (0000ff06-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb) could not be located on the device, null, null)
E/flutter (29808): #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:607:7)
E/flutter (29808): #1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:167:18)
E/flutter (29808): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (29808): #2      BluetoothCharacteristic.write (package:flutter_blue/src/bluetooth_characteristic.dart:120:18)
E/flutter (29808): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (29808): #3      DeviceScreen._buildServiceTiles.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:untitled/main.dart:176:23)
```

or another error saying : Write is not permited.
I'm using example code provided by flutter blue library, here is the code that im trying to write after device is connected:

```
onWritePressed: () async {
                      await c.write(_getRandomBytes(), withoutResponse: true);
                      await c.read();
                    },
                    onNotificationPressed: () async {
                      await c.setNotifyValue(!c.isNotifying);
                      if (c.properties.read) {
                        await c.read();
                      }
```

```
List<int> _getRandomBytes(){
String command = "55 AA 00 01 50 3C 00";
return command.codeUnits;
}
```

The hardware device is working fine in Kotlin, data is sent and received.

Comment: Are you writing to the correct characteristic? Please recheck for small typos in the uuids

Comment: Yes everything is correct. Trying to write in the characteristic which has a writeWithoutResponse property.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it can't find the service the characteristic belongs to (or whichever service has the uuid shown in the error). Try calling `discoverServices` before trying to write